# RuntimeException: Error inflating class android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**What i am doing**:: I am trying to display a tabbed viewpager

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener  {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the view from main_fragment.xml

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));


        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Tab3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "[onDestroy(activity)]");
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(arg0==1){
            fragment=new SortRestaurantFragment();
        }
        if(arg0==2){
            fragment=new SortRestaurantFragment();

        }
        if(arg0==3){
            fragment=new SortRestaurantFragment();

        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**I have also added the support libraries::**

[image]
[image]

**Log::**

```
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module/com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 11 more
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 20 more
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module/com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.findmybuffet.restaurant_module.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 11 more
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
02-10 02:34:17.471: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 20 more
```

### {Edit}

**main_activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Log ::**

```
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:389)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-10 03:02:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How have you added `android-support-v4.jar` to your project?

Comment: @CommonsWare .... Mark Murphy Please see the edit ... i have posted a stack trace after edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `main_activity.xml`, you have the class name spelled wrong.

```
android.suppoort.v4.view.ViewPager
```

should be

```
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

Comment: [+1] for pointing the typo but(i didnt notice that error even though im looking it for an hour ) ........ Still i have the same error ... even after making changes

Comment: You might want to post the new stack trace, since it's probably a different problem now.

Comment: @ ginovva320  ...... Yes ... its pointing a different error .... Please see the edit ...

Comment: I resolved the final error:: by changing get count returning value to 1 since i was returning one fragment for all the tabs